# SQL Query to pull a certain amount of results per item

Tags: sql, limit-per-group

I'm looking for a better way to generate a list just using sql instead of C#.  It seems simple enough that i'm doing it wrong

Say i have a table called PhoneNumbers, with Number/City/State

Example (but millions of numbers):

```
NUMBER          CITY        STATE
555-555-5555    New York    NY
111-111-1111    Los Angeles CA
222-222-2222    Houston     TX
333-333-3333    Miami       FL
```

I need a query that will return 10 phone numbers from each state

Right now i am individually just running a query against all 50 states and then combining them in a dataset, but it's a big database so it's slow, i am hoping there's a simple method to just pull back the data i need.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: please indicate which dbms type as solution options differ by type

Answer (score 0):

The below query should work for Oracle and SQL Server, but not for MySQL:

```
with cte as
(select number, city, state,
 row_number() over (partition by state order by state) rn
 from yourtable)

select number,city,state
from cte
where rn <= 10
```

Note that if you need the first 10 rows sorted by a particular field, you will have to tweak the `order by` to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

it differs, but for MSSQL:

```
with cteByStateas (
   select row_number() over (partition by STATE order by CITY) as RowNo,
          number,
          city,
          state
)
select * 
  from cteByState
 where RowNo <= 10
```

Please note that you didnt specify which first 10 numbers you want, or if they should be random

for mysql, there it is done a bit different, using a variable

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `UNION ALL` clause. Somthing like this:-

```
(SELECT NUMBER, CITY, STATE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE STATE = 'NY' ORDER BY CITY LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT NUMBER, CITY, STATE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE STATE = 'CA' ORDER BY CITY LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT NUMBER, CITY, STATE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE STATE = 'TX' ORDER BY CITY LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT NUMBER, CITY, STATE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE STATE = 'FL' ORDER BY CITY LIMIT 10)
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I think OP is already using this approach and wants another method.`Right now i am individually just running a query against all 50 states and then combining them in a dataset`

Comment: The user didn't put his query, thats why i m just giving him a solution which is much easier to understand.